# How to hide product in drupal commerce with rules

Tags: commerce, rules

I have a Drupal site with drupal commerce on it and I created a **product with 2 price field**.

If a user have role 'simple user' he sees the default price.
If user have role 'friend user' he sees the second price value.

I already create this rule but now I'm trying to filter the product in this way:

**If user have role 'friend user' and the product don't have the second price hide it** to him.
I'm not seeing any option in rule to hide a content.

How can I achieve this content filter?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is not out of the box or ready to use solution. You should create a custom rule and trigger it when the product is being viewed.